# PayPal API: What happens if DoExpressCheckoutPayment isn't called?

Tags: paypal

When using the classic PayPal API, what happens to an express checkout transaction in which DoExpressCheckoutPayment does not get called?

For example, if a user is sent to the PayPal site via a successful call to SetExpressCheckout, signs in and completes the sale on the PayPal and is sent back to my site via the ReturnURL field. At that point, what happens if the DoExpressCheckoutPaymet method is not called? Is there still a transaction waiting to be processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token would still be available for a little while yes, but the transaction is never complete until DECP is called.  You could circle back around and use the same token, though, or you could go through SetExpressCheckout again to obtain a new token.

Again, though, there is no actual transaction until DECP is completed successfully (unless you're working with recurring payments, in which case you may skip to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile).